# spring-cloud-starter-zipkin clash with jdbc?

Tags: java, spring, zipkin

My spring boot application has some problem.

Zipkin and jdbc can not coexist together.
It is normal to have only one zipkin or jdbc.

Maven dependency:

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-zipkin</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Exception:

```
2019-07-26 18:59:14.710  WARN [service-db,,,] 30448 --- [ender@1a6dc589}] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: 

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'eurekaRibbonClientConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'clientConfig';
```

Nested exception is:

`org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationNotAllowedException: Error creating bean with name 'eurekaClientConfigBean': Singleton bean creation not allowed while singletons of this factory are in destruction (Do not request a bean from a BeanFactory in a destroy method implementation!)`

Comment: Please update your question with what dependency versions you are using, it's impossible to know what the issue is without them

Answer (score 0):

Set the datasource setting in the application.yml file of the application as follows,

```
spring:
  dataSource:
    url: jdbc: mariadb://localhost:3306/test
    driverClassName: org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver
    username: test
    password: test
```

You can add the zipkin attribute to POM.xml

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-zipkin</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Problems can occur due to Spring's auto configuration property.

Therefore, modify the datasource setting as follows and modify the datasource configuration related source to make the application work normally.

```
myApp:
   dataSource:
     jdbc-url: jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3306/test
     driverClassName: org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver
     username: test
     password: test
```